# Variable not being recognized in method

Tags: java

I am relatively new to Java, and I am writing a simple program to play rock, paper, scissors. This is the code:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
  public static String comChoice() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int num = rand.nextInt(299) + 1;

    if (num >= 1 && num <= 99) {
      String pick = "SCISSORS";
    } else if (num >= 100 && num <= 199) {
      String pick = "ROCK";
    } else if (num >= 200 && num <= 299) {
      String pick = "PAPER";
    }
    return pick;
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    int wins = 0;
    int losses = 0;
    int ties = 0;
    while (1 == 1) {
      Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Would you like to play Rock Paper Scissors? Y/N");
      String n = s.next();

      if (n.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
        Scanner t = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your pick: rock, paper, or scissors");
        String userChoice = t.next();

        String pick = comChoice();

        if (userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("SCISSORS") && pick.equalsIgnoreCase("SCISSORS")) {
          System.out.println("TIE");
          ties++;
        } else if (userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("ROCK") && pick.equalsIgnoreCase("SCISSORS")) {
          System.out.println("WIN");
          wins++;
        } else if (userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("PAPER") && pick.equalsIgnoreCase("SCISSORS")) {
          System.out.println("LOSE");
          losses++;
        } else if (userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("SCISSORS") && pick.equalsIgnoreCase("ROCK")) {
          System.out.println("LOSE");
          losses++;
        } else if (userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("SCISSORS") && pick.equalsIgnoreCase("PAPER")) {
          System.out.println("WIN");
          wins++;
        } else {
          System.out.println("Enter a valid choice");
        }
      } else {
        System.out.println("You won " + wins + " matches");
        System.out.println("You tied " + ties + " matches");
        System.out.println("You lost " + losses + " matches");
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm getting an error in my method which says this:

```
Main.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
  return pick;
         ^
symbol:   variable pick
location: class Main
1 error

exit status 1
```

I can't figure out how to fix this error. I would appreciate your input as well as any other general advice

Thanks

Comment: learn about variable scope in java!

Comment: You're declaring variables inside the conditions. These aren't visible after the conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable is only visible in the `if` statement. Read about scopes.

Change to:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
    public static String comChoice() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int num = rand.nextInt(299) + 1;
        String pick = null;
        if (num >= 1 && num <= 99) {
            pick = "SCISSORS";
        } else if (num >= 100 && num <= 199) {
            pick = "ROCK";
        } else if (num >= 200 && num <= 299) {
            pick = "PAPER";
        }
        return pick;
    }

....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`pick` is out of scope. Try declaring at the start of the `comChoice` method.

Hence :

```
public static String comChoice() {
    String pick=null;
    Random rand = new Random();
    int num = rand.nextInt(299) + 1;

    if (num >= 1 && num <= 99) {
        pick = "SCISSORS";
    } else if (num >= 100 && num <= 199) {
        pick = "ROCK";
    } else if (num >= 200 && num <= 299) {
        pick = "PAPER";
    }
    return pick;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

variable `pick` is out of scope. You have to declare it outside the all `if else` statements. if all `if else` condition fail then `comChoice` method will not be able to find variable `pick` (as it is declared inside the if else block only)which it has to return.

corrected code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main
{
  public static String comChoice()
  {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int num = rand.nextInt(299) + 1;

    String pick = "";

    if(num >= 1 && num <= 99)
    {
      pick = "SCISSORS";
    }
    else if (num >= 100 && num <= 199)
    {
      pick = "ROCK";
    }
    else if (num >= 200 && num <= 299)
    {
      pick = "PAPER";
    }
    return pick;
  }
  public static void main (String args[])
  {
    int wins = 0;
    int losses = 0;
    int ties = 0;
    while (1 == 1)
    {
      Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in);
      System.out.println("Would you like to play Rock Paper Scissors? Y/N");
      String n = s.next();

      if (n.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
      {
        Scanner t = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your pick: rock, paper, or scissors");
        String userChoice = t.next();

        String pick = comChoice();

        if (userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("SCISSORS") && pick.equalsIgnoreCase("SCISSORS"))
        {
          System.out.println("TIE");
          ties++;
        }
        else if (userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("ROCK") && pick.equalsIgnoreCase("SCISSORS"))
        {
          System.out.println("WIN");
          wins++;
        }
        else if (userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("PAPER") && pick.equalsIgnoreCase("SCISSORS"))
        {
          System.out.println("LOSE");
          losses++;
        }
        else if (userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("SCISSORS") && pick.equalsIgnoreCase("ROCK"))
        {
          System.out.println("LOSE");
          losses++;
        }
        else if (userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("SCISSORS") && pick.equalsIgnoreCase("PAPER"))
        {
          System.out.println("WIN");
          wins++;
        }
        else
        {
          System.out.println("Enter a valid choice");
        }
      }
      else
      {
        System.out.println("You won " + wins + " matches");
        System.out.println("You tied " + ties + " matches");
        System.out.println("You lost " + losses + " matches");
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You declared your variable `pick` in the `if else` structure. Doing this causes the problem that your variable cannot be accessed from outside that `if else` structure. In simple words, the variable `pick`'s scope is limited to your `if else` structure. You have to declare your variable (and initialize it as well, otherwise you'll get an error in your case) outside of the `if else` structure. Like this:

```
String pick = null;
if(num >= 1 && num <= 99) {
...
...
...// All your if's and else's
}
return pick;
```

Hope this helps!